How can I turn on relevant lamps according to signal received from ThingSpeak in MATLAB?
We have sensors connected to power grid lines that will tell the status when there is any issue. We are trying to use ThingSpeak.  We performed some initial work as shown in this link.
Manually, our relevant lamps are working but we want to turn them on depending on the signal received from ThingSpeak. How we can proceed?
The channel ID is 543172.
